# How to overflow a full height content with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a layout with a full height side-menu and two tabs. In one of the two tabs, I have a very big (fixed height) content which overflow the body. I've set `overflow: auto` on the tab container.

I want the tabs to be full height and if the content overflow, a scroll. It barely works but the container on the second tab does not contain all the tab.

I've reproduced the bug on this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/L84M9rOgD

I've tried to use `align-items: start` on the tab container, it fixes the second tab but breaks the first one being full height..

Comment: Did you try adding `overflow: auto` to the div `.flex` ?

Comment: It makes the green div scrolling, but it's not what I want. I want the whole container to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6RVz35nXn)

**Add the below styles**

```
.panelContent {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.panelIsActive {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I want the whole container to scroll, not only the tab content. In my real app I have a content above the tabs and I need this to scroll also.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/meriadec/pen/mMRJPj?editors=0100)

The key to achieve this is to have the whole container having a *real* height (using `height: 100vh` or sticking it to whatever you want with `position: absolute`).

After that, things get easier, as the overflow will behave as expected. To ensure the `flex-grow` will not "compress" other blocks, ensure you have `flex-shrink: 0` set to siblings (cf demo, because it feel that my textual explanation is not *clear as crystal*).